# Processing: how can shapes form a text?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing

i wonder how this is made: http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage

Those spots form a text and when clicked , they explode.

How can shapes form a text? Can i achieve this with processing.js?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, the source code is there (linked in the lower left corner).

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way is to have a model for each character. For example, manually create the letter 'A' via shapes. Then for each letter in the message, you would display the character model for the letters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to write this in processing or in javascript. This is a javascript library, so you can use it in a javascript context. To make it on processing and use processingjs to display it on web you got to use processing resources to achieve the same result or manage to pass data from/to  javascript and processing. There is [this example](http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html#interface) from processingjs site on connecting your page with a processing sketch. Note that processingjs does not support use of processing libraries, so you can't use any of [Precessing typography](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/#typography_geometry) libraries in this workflow. I think that they could be very handy though...

As how doing this on processing, i think i would go for drawing letters in a not displayed PGraphics, and using a pixel color test on this surface to drive the drawings of the circles. This would allow to alter the text in run time. Like, in pseudo code

```
PGraphics matteImage = new PGraphics(size, size, render);//
matteImage.background(black);
matteImage.fill(255);
matteImage.text("A", x,y);
matteImage.loadPixels();

for(i; i < matteImage.length;i++)
{
 color c = matteImage.pixels[i];
  if ( c == white)
{
   doDrawEllipses();
}  
}
```

In drawing circles method/class i would add some noise/randomness, exploding handle...